# Get Android keyboard colors to add views with same color

Tags: android, layout

Do you know a way to get the current Android soft keyboard colors (especially background) so I can add a row of buttons on top with same colors?

Thanks!

[image: Toolbar above keyboard]

Answer (score 2):

There's no predefined color type assigned for IME. Keyboard can either use system colors but also provide own (i.e. Swype comes with variety of themes), so basically you seem out of luck

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I was thinking that maybe I could get it as a `View` to inspect it, but I guess it's impossible.